# DateTime Format check

Tags: c#

Quick Question

Value passed in `ActivationDate` or `ExpirationDate` string, must be in either of the two formats stated below:Format 1:`YYYY-MM-DD`  & Format 2: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`
If the date values are not in either of the above format, then it should report back appropriate error message.

Any clue? Thanks in advance

Comment: try to parse to those formats, if not possible you will get an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx), using a `string[]` with the valid formats:

```
string[] formats = new string[] { "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" };
string s = "2017-12-01 12:23";
DateTime date;
bool converted = DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

With this code, you get in `converted`if the input date was in a valid format, and in `date` the parsed `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ParseExact()` with `try-catch`:

```
string date = "2017-02-01";
DateTime dt = default(DateTime);

try
{
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, new string[] {"yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"}, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    //error
}
```

**OR**

Use `TryParseExact()`:

```
string date = "2017-02-01";
DateTime dt;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, new string[] {"yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm"}, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //do something and use "dt" variable
}
else
{
    //error
}
```

Comment: Thanks..now i am getting error for CultureInfo & DateTimeStyles.Which reference should i need to add for it ?

Comment: Add `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: Thank u so much :)